# how to get the file extension in pike

Tags: file, pike

I'm working on a program in pike and looking for a method like the *endswith()* in python- a method that gives me the extension of a given file.
Can someone help me with that? 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Python's *endswith()* is something like Pike's *has_suffix(string s, string suffix)*:

```
has_suffix("index.html", ".html");
```

Reference:
http://pike.lysator.liu.se/generated/manual/modref/ex/predef_3A_3A/has_suffix.html

Answer (score 0):

extract the end of the string, and compare it with the desired extension:

```
"hello.html"[<4..] == ".html"
```

(`<4` counts from the end of the string/array)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what the extension of a file is, just find the last dot and get the substring after it, e.g. `(str/".")[-1]`

If you just want to check if the file is of a certain extension, using has_suffix() is a good way, e.g. `has_suffix(str, ".html")`